Creating an enum with members whose attributes can be initialized
From this answer I learned how to create an enum with attributes (i.e. additional data):
from typing import NamedTuple

class EnumAttr(NamedTuple):
  data: str


class EnumWithAttrs(EnumAttr, Enum):
    GREEN = EnumAttr(data="hello")
    BLUE = EnumAttr(data="world")

EnumWithAttrs.GREEN.data

"hello"

I would now to do the following:
EnumWithAttrs.BLUE(data="yellow").data

'yellow'

Put differently: I want to be able to do the following:
a = EnumWithAttrs.BLUE(data="yellow")
b = EnumWithAttrs.BLUE(data="red")

I tried the following (and various variants of it), but it does not work:
from enum import Enum
from typing import Any, Callable, NamedTuple, Self

class EnumAttr(NamedTuple):
  data: str = ""

class EnumWithAttrs(EnumAttr, Enum):
    GREEN = EnumAttr(data="hello")
    BLUE = EnumAttr()

    def with_data(self, s: str) -> Self:
       self._replace(data=s)
       return self

x = EnumWithAttrs.BLUE.with_data("world")
x.data

''


this makes little sense for an enum.

Are you trying to have an enum with a callable for the value that returns EnumAttrs instance?
from enum import Enum
from typing import NamedTuple


class EnumAttr(NamedTuple):
    data: str
    @classmethod
    def with_data(cls, data):
        return cls(data)

class EnumWithAttrs(EnumAttr, Enum):
    GREEN = EnumAttr(data="hello")
    BLUE = EnumAttr(data='world')
    def __call__(self, data):
        return self.value.with_data(data)

Usage:
>>> EnumWithAttrs.BLUE
<EnumWithAttrs.BLUE: EnumAttr(data='world')>
>>> EnumWithAttrs.BLUE(data='TEST')
EnumAttr(data='TEST')


What you want to do is not possible, because enum members are singletons -- i.e. there is only ever one of EnumWithAttrs.BLUE 1.

1 The only exceptions to the singleton rule are when reloading modules with enums in them, or importing those modules under different names (and both those situations are bugs in the programmers' code).
